# How print list of tuples side by side

Tags: python, list, tuples

Just new to Python. And try to learn how I can print a list of tuples side by side. Let's say I have a list of tuple with a format of:

`myList =[('05', 5), ('08', 3), ('12', 5)]`

And I would like to have an output like:

```
05 5
08 3
12 5
```

without single quotes. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What if the length of the first element varies?

Comment: it's a log file and first element is hour. Most likely it won't have more than 2 digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is rather simple, you can, for instance, unpack the tuple in a for loop:

```
myList =[('05', 5), ('08', 3), ('12', 5)]

for a, b in myList:  # <-- this unpacks the tuple like a, b = (0, 1)
    print(a, b)
```

#### output:

```
05 5
08 3
12 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over it.

```
for value in myList:
    print(value[0], value[1])
```

Comment: Python already adds a space between two elements in a print statement. You can control this with the `sep` attribute.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. I have changed it. It's been a while since I had the opportunity to use print for anything but little bit of debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpacking, a feature in Python3:

```
myList =[('05', 5), ('08', 3), ('12', 5)]
for a, *b in myList:
  print(a, ' '.join(map(str, b)))
```

This way, if you have more than three elements in the tuple, you will not have an `ToManyValuesToUnpack` error raised.

Output:

```
05 5
08 3
12 5
```

For example:

```
myList =[('05', 5, 10, 3, 2), ('08', 3, 4), ('12', 5, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
for a, *b in myList:
   print(a, ' '.join(map(str, b)))
```

Output:

```
05 5 10 3 2
08 3 4
12 5 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: That certainly I was going to add, for multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

[python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) adds automatically a space between elements in the print statement. In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), we can use iterable unpacking:

```
for row in myList:
    print(*row)
```

producing:

```
>>> for row in myList:
...     print(*row)
... 
05 5
08 3
12 5
```

In case you want another separator (e.g. a pipe `|`), you can set the `sep` attribute:

```
for row in myList:
    print(*row, sep='|')
```

this produces:

```
>>> for row in myList:
...     print(*row,sep='|')
... 
05|5
08|3
12|5
```

This approach can handle any number of elements in the tuple (e.g. a list of 3-tuples), and in case the tuples have different lengths (e.g. `[(1,2),(3,4,5)]`), it will print the 3-tuples with three columns and the 2-tuples with two columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, j in myList:
    print(i, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution for a fixed tuple size of two, then this works:

```
for tup in myList:
    print(tup[0], tup[1])
```

If, though, you would prefer to print varying length tuples without changing your code, you could do something like this:

```
for tup in myList:
    print(' '.join(map(str,tup)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the values in a iterable, which works for more than two elements in tuple as well.

```
myList =[('05', 5, 3), ('08', 3), ('12', 5)]

for a in myList:
    print(*a, sep=" ")
```

You can use a different seperator, space is the default one.